# Converting Vector To Raster

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I have a polygon layer of Sassari region. The name of the layer is "ProtectedAreas_Sassaricomuni_mergedvector".

[image: vector layer to rasterize]

I want to raster this by simply giving the value 1 if the green patches exist, and 0 if they don't. The raster will be giving me information about the presence of the green layer.

I already assigned the values, 0 or 1 in the attribute table by creating a new column names "Presence_P".

[image: attribute table added column with values]

And these are the parameters I use to raster:
[image: rasterization window]

In the end the rasterized layer shows up in the list of layers but it doesn't generate any picture on the map.

Why am I having this issue?

Comment: I would suggest to remove `0` from `A fixed value to burn` field and change `0` to `-9999` or whatever in `Assign a specified nodata value to output bands` field. It seems that resulting raster has only 0s...